# How to prove $\lim_{z\rightarrow -i} (z^2 - z) =i-1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Prove $$\lim_{z\rightarrow -i} (z^2 - z) =i-1$$

I am trying to prove this but unable to find a reasonable solution,can someone help?

Comment: Here, you can just plug in $-i$ for $z$

Comment: $f(z)=z^2-z$ is a continuous function. Just substitute and done!

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: Please add some context, what you have tried, where you got stuck, how you arrived at this problem etc.

Comment: You do these kinds of basic complex limits in exactly the same way you would do similar real limits.

Comment: @fred,got it. Next step is: consider |z+i|=delta and it gets simplified further☺.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a $ \epsilon - \delta $- proof:

$|z^2-z-(i-1)|=|z^2+1-(z+i)|=|(z+i)(z-i)-(z+i)|=|z+i||z-i-1|$.

Since we are interested in $z \to -i$, we can assume that $|z| \le 2$. Hence we derive

$|z^2-z-(i-1)| \le |z+i|(|z|+2) \le 4|z+i|$.

Can you proceed ?